# Using the IN Clause With Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I'm in need of your hands.

I have 2 windows forms in c#.net where 1st form contains checked list box , collecting the ids from that box passing the value to the second form where i have written a stored procedure like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GDE_QA]
@oks_ids varchar(100),
@Operation varchar(50) 
AS BEGIN
    declare @Execute as varchar(100)

    set @Execute = 'select oks_id, path from tb_gde_qc where status=''QC Completed'' and oks_id in '''+@oks_ids+'''';

exec(@Execute) 
END
```

Now I want to pass the value for the parameter `@oks_ids`. For example

```
select oks_id, path 
from tb_gde_qc 
where status=''QC Completed'' 
  and oks_id in ('GD_01358', 'GD_01361', 'GD_01363')
```

Can anyone help me? Will be thankful to all

Comment: See Erland Sommarskog's seminal article [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005 and Beyond](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html) on various ways to handle this in SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GDE_QA]
@oks_ids varchar(100),
@Operation varchar(50) 
AS BEGIN
    declare @Execute as varchar(100)

    set @Execute = 'select oks_id, path from tb_gde_qc where status=''QC Completed'' and oks_id in '''+@oks_ids+'''';

sp_ExecuteSQL @Execute 
END
```

sp_ExecuteSQL should be able to handle the passing of the string within the parameter.

Can I ask where does @Operation come into play?